# Displaying shapefiles on IOS app

Tags: shapefile, ios, arcgis-ios

I need to write a simple app for IPad that displays maps I was given. All maps are in one folder and they are shapefiles. I am able to open them in ArcGIS for desktop, however I am unable to attach them to iOS application. I've gone through the tutorial with iOS SDK, however they use .tpk files. I converted my maps into .tpk, however my iOS app crashes when I try to open that converted tpk file, unlike other tpk files provided in tutorials. Could someone give me the direction with this problem?